# How to merge two rows into one single row in same table using max case

Tags: sql-server

I want to write procedure that merge two rows into one single row with the same Id

Also, if the the I'd is different keep the row as it's

Using max case

Comment: You'll need to provide quite a few more details in order for your Post to be answerable. Please provide the tables with their definitions, some sample data in them, and the expected results, minimally.